# Keep text format line by line Into variable to .txt PHP

Tags: php

```
<form action="editinfo.php" method="post">
    <pre><textarea rows="440" name="editinfo" cols="700"></textarea></pre><br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="ButtonSub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

editinfo.php

```
$editinfo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connd, $_POST['editinfo']);
$myfile = fopen("myinfo.txt", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $editinfo);
fclose($myfile);
```

What I want to achieve?
Let's say I have editinfo text is

```
SAM
PLEM
```

it outputs `SAM\r\nPLEM` in the txt, how can I format it correctly? so it can look like

```
SAM
PLEM
```

Comment: You might be interested in this: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: the variable was previously written into the SQL but since Im trying to make a better system I was changing to txt to handle those informations, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *don't* SQL-escape (`mysqli_real_escape_string`) the text, that's what's turning a linebreak into escaped `\r\n` sequences. There's absolutely no point in SQL escaping something that isn't going to be used in an SQL query.